# How to call to unmanaged WinCrypt.CryptQueryObject?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I want to pass binary blob pointer data to CryptQueryObject (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptqueryobject)
as it stated in documentation it can work with pointer to filename, or pointer to just binary blob, it works fine when I pass `(c# string)`
 (there are another overloading with string in WinCrypt.cs with `(c# string)` in it).

So How to pass the pointer to unmanaged DLL properly from c#?

[image]

what I have so far:

```
byte[] BinaryData = // what I Really have as data;
IntPtr pvContext = IntPtr.Zero;
unsafe {
 // NOTE(---): WARNING !!! UNSAFE UNMANAGED CODE
 GCHandle pinnedBinaryData = GCHandle.Alloc(BinaryData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
 IntPtr pointer = pinnedBinaryData.AddrOfPinnedObject();


 WinCrypt.CryptQueryObject(WinCrypt.CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB, pointer, WinCrypt.CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_CRL,
  WinCrypt.CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
  IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref pvContext);

 pinnedBinaryData.Free();
}
// NOTE(---): this is my overloading in WinCrypt.cs
[DllImport("CRYPT32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool CryptQueryObject(
 int dwObjectType,
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] IntPtr pvObject,
 int dwExpectedContentTypeFlags,
 int dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags,
 int dwFlags,
 IntPtr pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
 IntPtr pdwContentType,
 IntPtr pdwFormatType,
 IntPtr phCertStore,
 IntPtr phMsg,
 ref IntPtr ppvContext
);
```

Comment: I'm presuming that your `binary blob pointer data` is an array of bytes in C# that you want to Marshal to `CryptQueryObject`?

Comment: @martin, yes it's byte[]